# Permission denied when opening a file written using C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, permissions

I was doing some simple exercices with file descriptors with the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int fd1 = open("etc/passwd", O_RDONLY);
    int fd2 = open("output.txt", O_CREAT,O_TRUNC,O_WRONLY);

    dup2(fd1,0);
    close(fd1);

    dup2(fd2,1);
    close(fd2);
}
```

Whenever I try to open the "output.txt" i get the following error:

```
Unable to open 'output.txt': Unable to read file '/home/joao/Desktop/Exercicios/output.txt' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/joao/Desktop/Exercicios/output.txt').
```

Even though I believe some of the error refers to VSCode, I'm unable to open the file anywhere. Here is what I get when executing "ls -l" on the folder that has the .c file, the executable and the "output.txt":

```
---------T 1 joao joao     0 jun  9 21:54 output.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 joao joao 16784 jun  9 21:54 test
-rw-rw-r-- 1  700 joao   387 jun  9 21:54 teste.c
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `open("output.txt", O_CREAT,O_TRUNC,O_WRONLY);` -> `open("output.txt", O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY);`

Comment: It was right in front of my eyes... Thank you!

Comment: @kaylum There's a third parameter (`mode`) when using `open` to create a new file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
int fd2 = open("output.txt", O_CREAT,O_TRUNC,O_WRONLY);
```

is not right. *All* the flags go in the second argument, combined with bitwise or, and the third is for the "mode", i.e. the access rights. See [the manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) for much more details, of course.

So, it should be:

```
const int fd2 = open("output.txt", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, S_IRWXU);
```

this will open with the mode `S_IRWXU`, i.e. permissions are granted to read/write/execute for the owner only.